# jQuery-UI autocomplete menus show on init

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, internet-explorer-11

I tried my web site on Chrome and it worked well. But when I tried it on IE 11, all my autocomplete menus appeared on random locations on the screen. Strange behavior...

Its happens only when the page load (the inputs are invisible but the autocomplete menus are became visible), after I click on them they disappear and work normally.

What can I do about this?

**JS:**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#field-name").autocomplete({
        source: [
            {label: "Foo", value: 1},
            {label: "Bar", value: 2},
            {label: "Baz", value: 3}
        ],
        select: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.value);
        },
        close: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).trigger("change");
        },
        delay: 10,
        minLength: 0
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;">
    <input type="text" id="field-name" placeholder="Enter name" />
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post some HTML and CSS to specify your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that its strange behavior of IE with the `input` event. The event in invoked even if the input field is empty (with placeholder) on loading.

Comment: true , if there is a placeholder , it  triggers it on IE